# Right paren before dot in Flash with Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, adobe

trying to build a custom pod for Adobe Connect.

Found some source code, trying to replicate in my code for a simple drag and drop. The error message tells me it's expecting a "right paren before dot" on the third to last line of text below. I've been at this for a few days now with simple errors and I'm just totally stuck!

```
connector.dispatchSyncMessage("MouseEvent", Expo, true);

connector.addEventListener(SyncSwfEvent.SYNC_MSG_RCVD, mouselisten);

function mouseListen(e.SyncSwfEvent): void {
    if (e.data.msgNm == "MouseEvent") {
        expo = e.data.msgVal as Array;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `e:SyncSwfEvent` as an argument of `mouseListen` function. Like: `function mouseListen(e:SyncSwfEvent)`

Comment: Hi, no joy - it brought up more errors about property being undefined.

Comment: show these new errors

Comment: Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 377, Column 9 1120: Access of undefined property expo.

Comment: Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 373, Column 56 1120: Access of undefined property mouselisten.

Comment: cause one time you use `mouselisten` but another is `mouseListen`, then you use `Expo` and `expo`.. check your variables and functions names, ActionScript is case-sensitive

Comment: two new errors:

Comment: Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 379, Column 23 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Array to an unrelated type flash.display:MovieClip.
Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 375, Column 56 1120: Access of undefined property mouselisten.

Comment: Managed down to one error:

Comment: Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 378, Column 23 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Array to an unrelated type flash.display:MovieClip.

Comment: Have you defined the variable expo type somewhere? Are you sure that is array?

Comment: I'll be honest - i don't know what that means. As I say, very new to this!